# function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed>

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with three embedded `UINavigationController`s. The app runs perfectly on my device, but on a few other test devices, I'm getting the crash: `function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed>` in Crashlytics.

This is the report I'm getting in Crashlytics.

[image]

And this is the code I'm using to set up my `UIPageViewController`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    private var pages: [UINavigationController]!

    private var currentPageIndex: Int!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {


        } else {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSignup", sender: self)

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Page view controller is initial VC, but if FB Access Token is nil, redirect to signup flow
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

            self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self

            self.pages = [
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiscoverNav") as! UINavigationController,
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LiveFeedNav") as! UINavigationController,
                self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileNav") as! UINavigationController
            ]

            (self.pages[0].topViewController as! DiscoverViewController).parentPageViewController = self
            (self.pages[1].topViewController as! LiveFeedViewController).parentPageViewController = self
            (self.pages[2].topViewController as! ProfileViewController).parentPageViewController = self


            self.currentPageIndex = 1
            let startingViewController = self.pages[1] as UINavigationController
            self.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        } else {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSignup", sender: self)

        }

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying last view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no next view controller
        return (self.currentPageIndex == self.pages.count - 1 ? nil : self.pages[self.currentPageIndex + 1])
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = (self.pages as NSArray).indexOfObject(viewController)
        self.currentPageIndex = index

        // if currently displaying first view controller, return nil to indicate that there is no previous view controller
        return (index == 0 ? nil : self.pages[index - 1])
    }



    func displayPageForIndex(index: Int, animated: Bool = true) {
        assert(index >= 0 && index < self.pages.count, "Error: Attempting to display a page for an out of bounds index")

        // nop if index == self.currentPageIndex
        if self.currentPageIndex == index { return }

        if index < self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if index > self.currentPageIndex {
            self.setViewControllers([self.pages[index]], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        self.currentPageIndex = index
    }

}
```

Now it seems as if the crash is coming from the `ProfileViewController.swift`, however nothing ever gets called from that page when the `UIPageView` loads. On lines 16 & 17 of the Crashlytics report, it's pointing to the PageViewController. Doesn't appear to be much information on this error out there, but from what I've read it sounds like it has something to do with a nil value somewhere. Can anyone offer advice on this?

And line 47 on the PageViewController points to `self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileNav") as! UINavigationController`

Comment: did you try without unwrapping those optionals? `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileNav") as? UINavigationController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that some test users were trying to open the TestFlight invitation from their Gmail app, which apparently you're not supposed to do. I told them to open from Safari or Apple Mail and it worked. Thanks for the extra headache TestFlight.

Comment: That's a Gmail problem that's not unique to TestFlight. Gmail gates people into their web browser…similar to Facebook. Blame Google.